# How to disable the rule .MuiInputBase-inputType-121 in Material UI TextField for email field due to display issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-ui, mui

I have the following JSX:

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField/TextField';


                <Col xs={6}>
                  <TextField
                    pattern=".{3,}"
                    name="fullName"
                    label={intl.formatMessage(messages.fullName)}
                    type="text"
                    margin="normal"
                    fullWidth
                  />
                </Col>
                <Col xs={6}>
                  <TextField
                    name="email"
                    label={intl.formatMessage(messages.email)}
                    type="email"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                  />
                </Col>
```

For some reason, there is this css applied on the **email** field:

```
.MuiInputBase-inputType-121 {
    height: 1.1875em;
}
```

This is only applied to the email field, so this is the issue:

[image]

Disabling this rule restore the display.

How should I configure `.MuiInputBase-inputType-121` properly ?

Comment: I noticed you imported TextFieldMui instead of just TextField. Did you customized your Textfield?

Comment: Yes, [`InputBase`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/InputBase/InputBase.js) applies this style to any input where the type is not "text", but I do not see any odd effects from this like you show. Please share a CodeSandbox that reproduces this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to the TextField in CSS so all the fields have same properties